How to send a solana instruction with big data?
I want to send a raw data much bigger maybe with a 2048 length.
Also I want to pass data as instruction data.
While I build the transaction and execute, it told me the size is too big.
How can I do that ? I don't want to split even 800 trunks , cause that will cause too much traffics and too much gas. How can I do?

Sadly the maximum transaction size is 1232 bytes and you can not send more.
Options to save space in your transaction are using address lookup tables or writing the data in an account in another transaction and use the data from that account.
Address lookup tables can be used to save space in transactions by saving account addresses in another account and then only passing in a pointer to that address in the real transaction.
https://solana.com/de/docs/advanced/lookup-tables
